# How to get last executed statement on a particular table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, trigger, insert, ddl, oracle-sql-developer

Trying to identify what ghost process is inserting records into a particular table. Is there a way to get the exact query?

Comment: The only way to accurately capture who is doing what is to enable auditing on the table.

Comment: Auditing (or trigger-based logging) is the only sure-fire way. You might be able to identify it with ASH data if the insert operation took more than a few seconds of time. Find SQL in the shared pool that would insert records into your table (using `v$sqlarea` or `v$sql_plan`) and then look for it by `sqlid` in `v$active_session_history` and `dba_hist_active_sess_history`.

Comment: @PaulW You would need Diagnostick Pack to query those tables just for info.

Comment: @paganini, yes, the latter two mentioned views. But most Oracle shops have Tuning & Diagnostics. If you don't, you could always write your own 1-second wait polling engine to implement your own ASH-style data, but that's probably more work than it's worth for this need.